# SimpleForm: Why password text box does not show on form in Rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In user update page, there is a password field which is added to the form with `attr_accessor`:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

The view code for those 2 fields in `_form.html.erb` is :

```
  <div id='div_user_password'>
  <%= f.input :password, :label => t('Password'), :hint => t('6 characters or more')  %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => t('Password Confirmation') %>
  </div>
```

The erb code had no problem before. After removing a few fields (no change for `password and password_confirmation` though) from the `_form.html.erb`, however, the text box for password disappeared (see attached below). The html source for the `password` is:

```
<label class="password optional control-label" for="user_password">
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: EN.Password">Password</span>
</label>
```

There is missing `<input id = ....>` for the `password` in the html source code. What could cause the missing of the text box for `password`? If we rename field to `password_new` from `password`, then the text box shows up. Is it a bug of simple_form (version 2.1.1)? We use bootstrap.

[image]

Comment: After deleting a jquery.min file under public/assets/, the page starts acting normally. The old assets seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please using `attr_accessible` instead.

Comment: Password has been added to attr_accessible since the beginning. Password is not a column in our db table and is only a field on the form.

Comment: Same after removing password from attr_accessor

Comment: @user938363 And what the exact simple_form version you used?

Comment: simple for version 2.1.1